# jquery toggle button image play/stop

Tags: jquery, toggle

Hi I am using the following script to change a button image to toggle between play and stop:

```
<input type="image" src="../../Content/images/play.png" name="btn" style="width:22; height:22;"  />
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').bind("click", function () {
                if ($(this).attr("scr") == "../../Content/images/play.png")
                    $(this).attr("scr", "../../Content/images/puase.png");
                else
                    $(this).attr("scr", "../../Content/images/play.png");
            });
        });
```

It does not work, would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: i don't know what is "scr" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var is_play = true;

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        if (is_play){
            is_play  = false;
            $(this).attr("src", "../../Content/images/puase.png");
        }
        else{
            $(this).attr("src", "../../Content/images/play.png");
            }
    });
});
```

also add `id="btn"` to  :

```
<input type="image" id="btn" src="../../Content/images/play.png" name="btn" style="width:22; height:22;"  />
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was also missing id="btn".

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$('input[name=btn]').bind("click", function () {
```

And also change `scr` to `src`